# quick sort not working returning same array

Tags: c++, array-algorithms

Part method is not doing anything it outputs same array as entered and i don't know whats wrong

```
void part(int array[100], int start, int end){
  int pivot = array[start];
  int i = start;
  int j = end;
  int temp, temp2;
  // i to swap elements greater than pivot
  // j to swap elements less than or equal to pivot
  while(i > j){
    while(true){
      if(array[i] <= pivot ){
        break;
      }
      ++i;
    }
    while(array[j] > pivot){
      if(array[j] > pivot){
        break;
      }
      --j;
    }
    if(i < j){
      temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
  }
  if(j < i){                                    // j - i cross each other
    temp2 = pivot;
    pivot = array[j];
    pivot = temp2;
  }

  for(int k = 0; k<end;++k){
    cout<<array[k];
  }


}

void quick(int array[100], int start, int end){
  if(start < end){
    part(array, start, end);
  }


}
```

Comment: How do you use `quick` and `part`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Note that the body of the loop `while(i > j)` won't be executed when `start <= end`.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: quick method  will just be used to recurisevly call part and part has to sort the array

Comment: Also note that your program looks dangerous because there are no limit of `i` in the loop `while(true)` and `array[i]` may become out-of-range. `while(array[j] > pivot)` loop is safe if `end` is in-range because the loop is breaked when `array[j] > pivot` (the same condition as loop condition!)

Comment: i was using the same version earlier but i did for some change lol

Comment: `temp2 = pivot; pivot = array[j]; pivot = temp2;` looks weird because the last 2 statements do effectively nothing and it can be written as `temp2 = pivot;` (assuming that `array[j]` is in-range).

Comment: Why all this instead of just calling [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) ? It is *usually* good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `part` only if

```
if(start < end){
    part(array, start, end);
```

but then you do

```
int i = start;
int j = end;

while(i > j){
```

So, it is expected this will do nothiong. The `while` will never enter.